# espresso test ignores IdlingResouce isIdle() returning false

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

There is an IdlingResource, e.g. like this

```
public class IRWatchlistNamesLoaded implements IdlingResource {

private final static String CLASSNAME = "IRWatchlistNamesLoaded";
private ResourceCallback callback;

public IRWatchlistNamesLoaded () {}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return getClass().getName();
}

@Override
public boolean isIdleNow() {
    if(LMaxApplication.watchlists.getNames() != null && LMaxApplication.watchlists.getNames().size() > 0) {
        callback.onTransitionToIdle();
        CustomLog.print(CustomLog.UI_TEST, CLASSNAME, "isIdleNow = TRUE. size  = " + LMaxApplication.watchlists.getNames().size());
        return true;
    }
    CustomLog.print(CustomLog.UI_TEST, CLASSNAME, "isIdleNow = FALSE. size  = " + LMaxApplication.watchlists.getNames().size());
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.callback = resourceCallback;
}
```

}

And the usage is standard - when I need the resource I call

```
 watchlistLoadedIR = new IRWatchlistNamesLoaded();
 needToUnregisterWatchlistLoadedIR = true;
 Espresso.registerIdlingResources(watchlistLoadedIR);
```

What I see in logs is that isIdle() returns false (1 or 2 times), my test keeps going and my resource is not loaded properly, so test fails. Also, need to notice that in some other tests this IdlingResource works and espresso really waits for the resource to be idle. The usage is absolutely the same.
Please, maybe somebody has any idea why this could happen?

Comment: What does the rest of your test look like? I.e. what comes after `Espresso.registerIdlingResources(watchlistLoadedIR);`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but there is a great way of setting up IdlingResources described [here](http://www.geekhole.uk/?p=16) which might help solve your problem. I have a sneaking suspicion that it has to do with the fact that you are instantiating your class within the test, which I don't think is what you want to be doing, since you need to be using the IdlingResources from with an activity, using onView to perform action on different components which would then end up running the class in question.

Comment: haven't seen such implementation yet.. I'm not sure that using testing framework should influence the code.. anyway thanks for the link! if it solves my problem I'll mark your answer as correct.